# HTML - How to style a input type=submit so no second line created?

Tags: html

I am tring to style a input submit button like an anchor.
But it is putting a second line underneath the anchor.

How do I style just one line?

```
.usernameAnchor
{
    background-color:white;
    color: #034af3;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 0px none;
    display:inline;
    height:25px;
}
```

Malcolm

EDIT: This problem is in IE8.

Comment: Could you add your HTML?

Comment: also add the browser name and there version no. where it working properly.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be working fine as I created and checked that here:

http://jsbin.com/adake3/2

Looks like there is something there with your html markup.

### Update:

After seeing your code, you are trying to set the `text-decoration` to `underline`, but mind you this is a button not a link. One alternative is to give `border-bottom` to it to mimic underlining something like this:

```
  .usernameAnchor:hover
  {
    border-bottom:1px solid #0000ff;
  }
```